# Why is this code producing an indent error?

Tags: python-3.x, printf, syntax-error, indentation

There is an issue in my indentation that is preventing anything from printing. I think it is related to the indentation with def main and main, but I am not completely sure. If you notice any other issues, please let me know. It is giving me an Indentation Error when I have def main and main on the same indentation, and no error (but also print functions do not do anything) when main is indented one tab further.

class collapseIntervals(object):

```
def __init__(self, intervals_object, intervals_tuples):

    def open_file(self):
        intervals_object = open("intervals.txt", "r")
        intervals_object.readline()
        print(intervals_object)


    def main():


        main()
```

def main and main at same indentation (see below): Expected Indent
def main():
main()

main indented further than def main: process finished with exit code 0 (but no prints actually print to the console)
def main():
    main()

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine for me, my guess is that you are mixing spaces and tabs please see https://medium.com/@peey/what-is-the-inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation-error-and-why-is-it-caused-f3bbb8b2568b

This works as expected:

```
def __init__(self, intervals_object, intervals_tuples):

    def open_file(self):
        intervals_object = open("intervals.txt", "r")
        intervals_object.readline()
        print(intervals_object)


    def main():

        main()
```